# Plotly show minor tick values

Tags: python, plotly

In Python, I'm making a large figure with 15 subplots using Plotly.
On these subplots, I want to indicate some important points along the x-axis. Initially, I used fig.add_vline to draw a vertical line + a label at these points. For some reason, this is extremely slow:

```py
import time
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

n = 15
fig = make_subplots(n, 1)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(0, 3000, 5), y=np.random.randn(600), mode="lines"),  row=i, col=1)
    
for point in range(0,3000,300):
    fig.add_vline(x=point, line_width=2, line_dash="dash", line_color="green", annotation_text="test")
    
fig.show()
```

Takes 16 seconds.

Therefore, I tried to achieve something similar by setting the figure's tickvalues and ticktext to the values and labels of the points that I want to indicate.

```py
fig = make_subplots(n, 1)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(0, 3000, 5), y=np.random.randn(600), mode="lines"),  row=i, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=True,  tickmode="array", tickvals=list(range(300, 3000, 300)),
                 ticktext=['test']*10, gridcolor="green", griddash='dash', gridwidth=2)
fig.show()
```

This takes about 0.2 seconds which is perfect. It gives a figure with almost the same information except for the values on the xaxis. I'd like to still show these as well.
I thought of doing this by adding minor ticks and showing their values as well but I don't manage to do this. How can I do this or resolve this in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is to improve speed and add minor ticks, first, as a speed improvement, stop vertical lines that are shapes and add vertical lines in scatter plot line mode. x-axis is a list of the same locations, y-axis is from y0 to y1. String annotations would be added to the same loop, with the x-axis being a single value and the y-axis being the value you want the text to appear as. Just add a little more y-axis range since the text may be cut off. If you do not need a minimum and maximum for each graph, the code is even simpler.

```
import time
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

n = 15
fig = make_subplots(n, 1)

minmax = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    a = np.random.randn(600)
    minmax.append([a.min(),a.max()])
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(0, 3000, 5), y=a, mode="lines"), row=i, col=1)

for i,val in zip(range(1, n+1), minmax):
    for point in range(0,3000,300):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[point, point],
                                 y=[val[0], val[1]],
                                 mode='lines',
                                 line_width=2,
                                 line_dash="dash",
                                 line_color="green",
                                 text='text',
                                 textposition='top right',
                                 showlegend=False), row=i, col=1)
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[point],
                                 y=[a.max()],
                                 mode='text',
                                 text='text',
                                 textposition='top right',
                                 showlegend=False), row=i, col=1)
        fig.update_yaxes(range=[val[0], val[1]+0.8])
        
fig.update_xaxes(minor_ticks='outside')
fig.update_layout(height=2000)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is the other alternative solution I thought of as well, It does the job. Unfortunately it lacks the "infinite scrolling" posiblity which I like with vline. Any idea why shapes are so slow?

Comment: My guess is that numerous shapes are degrading performance.